# Modificar datos de usuario logueado (PHP + MySQL)

Tags: php, mysql, base-de-datos, pdo

Estoy haciendo una web en la que he añadido registros de usuario, y estoy intentando que un usuario ya logueado pueda meterse en su perfil y modificar sus datos de usuario a través de una consulta en la BD, pero me da el siguiente error y no sé como hacerlo exactamente...

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Código del formulario para modificar los datos del usuario

```
<?php
session_start();
    require_once ("navegacion.php");
    require_once ('index.php');
    
 
    if (isset($_SESSION['usuario']))
        $mostrarUsuario =$_SESSION['usuario'];
    else {
        header("location:login.php"); 
    }
    
    if (isset($_POST['actualizar'])) {
      
        $controlador = new ControladorUsuario();
        $controlador->actualizar();
    } 
     
    ?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="es">
    <head>

        <title>Saving Paws</title>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css.css">

    </head>

    <body>

        <form method="POST" id="registro">
            <div class="login-page"> 
                <div class="form">
                    <form class="register-form">
                        <h2>Modificar datos de usuario</h2><br>
                        <input type="text" placeholder="Nombre" id="nombre" name="nombre_a" required="" />  <br/><br/> 
                        <input type="text" placeholder="Apellidos" id="apellidos" name="apellidos_a" required=""/>   <br/><br/>  
                        <input type="password" placeholder="Contraseña" id="contraseña" name="password_a" required=""/> <br/><br/>
                        <input type="text" placeholder="Dirección" id="direccion" name="direccion_a" required=""/>   <br/><br/>
                        <input type="text" placeholder="Ciudad" id="ciudad" name="ciudad_a" required=""/>   <br/><br/>
                        <input type="email" placeholder="Correo electrónico" id="email" name="email_a" required=""/>   <br/><br/>
                        <input  type="number" id="telefono" placeholder="Teléfono" name="numero_a" required=""/>   <br/><br/>
                        <input type="submit" value="Actualizar" name="actualizar" id="botones"/>
                    </form>
                    </body>
                    </html>
```

Este es el código donde tengo las clases y esta es la función de registro, donde creo la variable de inicio de sesión:

```
class ControladorUsuario {

    public function registro() {
        require 'config.php';
        if (isset($_POST['registrarse'])) { //si has pulsado el boton de registrarse
            $name_reg = $_POST['name_reg'];
            $lastname_reg = $_POST['lastname_reg'];
            $email_reg = $_POST['email_reg'];
            $password_reg = $_POST['password_reg'];
            $password_regconf = $_POST['password_regconf'];
            $direction_reg = $_POST['direction_reg'];
            $city_reg = $_POST['city_reg'];
            $number_reg = $_POST['number_reg'];

            //para saber si el usuario que se va a registrar existe:
            $existente = $base->query("SELECT * FROM usuario WHERE email='$email_reg'");
            //busca en la tabla de usuarios si ya existe el email que se intenta registrar
            if ($existente->rowCount() > 0) { //si da un nº de filas superior a 0, significa que ya esta este email
                echo 'Ya existe el email';
            } else if ($password_reg != $password_regconf) { //comprueba que la pass sea igual
                echo 'Las contraseñas no coinciden';
            } else {
                try {
                    $nuevoUsuario = $base->prepare("INSERT INTO usuario(nombre, apellidos, email, 
            password, direccion, ciudad, telefono) VALUES (:name_reg, :lastname_reg, :email_reg, 
            :password_reg, :direction_reg, :city_reg, :number_reg)");
                    $nuevoUsuario->bindParam(':name_reg', $name_reg, PDO::PARAM_STR, 40); //significa q sera string
                    $nuevoUsuario->bindParam(':lastname_reg', $lastname_reg, PDO::PARAM_STR, 20);
                    $nuevoUsuario->bindParam(':email_reg', $email_reg, PDO::PARAM_STR, 30);
                    $nuevoUsuario->bindParam(':password_reg', $password_reg, PDO::PARAM_STR, 10);
                    $nuevoUsuario->bindParam(':direction_reg', $direction_reg, PDO::PARAM_STR, 60);
                    $nuevoUsuario->bindParam('city_reg', $city_reg, PDO::PARAM_STR, 25);
                    $nuevoUsuario->bindParam(':number_reg', $number_reg, PDO::PARAM_INT, 15);

                    $nuevoUsuario->execute();
                } catch (PDOException $error) {//si hay algun error imprime:
                    print 'ERROR' . $error->getMessage();
                    echo 'Error al registrarse, intentalo de nuevo';
                    print 'ERROR' . $error->getMessage();
                }

//muestra el ultimo registro añadido a la bd
                $lastInsertId = $base->lastInsertId();
                if ($lastInsertId > 0) {

                    echo "<div class='content alert alert-primary' > Bienvenido $name_reg  </div>";
                } else {
                    echo "<div class='content alert alert-danger'> No se ha podido agregar </div>";

                    print_r($nuevoUsuario->errorInfo());
                }
            }
        } else {
            echo "Función POST no ejecutada";
        }
    }

    public function login() {
        require 'config.php';

        $sql = "SELECT * FROM usuario WHERE email= :email AND password= :password";

        $resultado = $base->prepare($sql);

        $email = htmlentities(addslashes($_POST["email"]));

        $password = htmlentities(addslashes($_POST["password"]));

        $resultado->bindValue(":email", $email);

        $resultado->bindValue(":password", $password);

        $resultado->execute();

        $numero_registro = $resultado->rowCount(); //creamos variable

        if ($numero_registro != 0) { //si el usuario si existe en nuestra bd inicia sesion
            session_start();

   
            $_SESSION["usuario"] = $resultado->fetch(PDO::FETCH_OBJ); //almacenamos en la variable super global sesion el login del usuario

 /*           if (!isset($_SESSION['usuario'])){
                
            }*/

            header("location:portada.php"); //redirige a menu de users registrados si esta todo correcto
        } else {
            echo 'datos incorrectos';
            header("location:login.php"); //redirige de nuevo al login si el usuario se equivoca en los datos
        }
    }
```

y esta es la función en la que hago la consulta a la base de datos para modificar los datos del usuario logueado

```
 public function actualizar() {
        require 'config.php';
        
        if (isset($_POST['actualizar'])) {
                 
$nombre=($_POST['nombre_a']);
$apellidos=($_POST['apellidos_a']);
$email=($_POST['email_a']);
$password=($_POST['password_a']);
$direccion=($_POST['direccion_a']);
$ciudad=($_POST['email_a']);
$telefono=($_POST['numero_a']);
$id=$_SESSION['usuario'];
      
        }
 
        $modificar = $base->prepare( "UPDATE usuario
SET nombre = :nombre, apellidos = :apellidos, email = :email, password = :password,
direccion = :direccion, ciudad = :ciudad, telefono = :telefono
WHERE :id = $id");
        
        
        
        $modificar->bindParam(":nombre",$nombre,PDO::PARAM_STR, 25);
        $modificar->bindParam(":apellidos",$apellidos,PDO::PARAM_STR, 25);
        $modificar->bindParam(":email",$email,PDO::PARAM_STR,25);
        $modificar->bindParam(":password",$password,PDO::PARAM_STR,25);
        $modificar->bindParam(":direccion",$direccion,PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $modificar->bindParam(":ciudad",$ciudad,PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $modificar->bindParam(":telefono",$telefono,PDO::PARAM_INT);
        $modificar->bindParam(":id",$id->id, PDO::PARAM_INT);
        
        $modificar->execute();
        
        header('location:perfilUsuario.php');
        
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Lo que sucede es que en tu consulta estas utilizando tu variable $id que es un objeto como si fuera un String, en este caso, para construir la consulta debes pasarla como un parámetro para que con el `bindParam` funcione la asignación del valor del ID.

En este caso $modificar quedaría de la siguiente forma:

```
$modificar = $base->prepare( "UPDATE usuario
SET nombre = :nombre, apellidos = :apellidos, email = :email, password = :password,
direccion = :direccion, ciudad = :ciudad, telefono = :telefono
WHERE id = :id");
```

Comment: Te refieres a que a la función le debo psar el parametro $id? public function actualizar(int $id) ?

Comment: Por lo que veo, el parámetro lo obtienes desde `$id=$_SESSION['usuario'];` y ya lo estas asignando en `$modificar->bindParam(":id",$id->id, PDO::PARAM_INT);` lo único que haría falta es corregir la sentencia `WHERE :id = $id` ya que es incorrecta porque $id es un objeto y lo manejas como string, debería de ser `WHERE id = :id`

Comment: Arreglado! muchas gracias ^^